# Java String ReplaceFirst

Tags: java, string, replace, split

I am reading in a string

```
Is Mississippi a State where there are many systems.
```

I would like to replace the 1st "s" or "S" in each word with "t" or "T" (i.e keeping the same case)...so that the output is:

```
It Mitsissippi a Ttate where there are many tystems.
```

I have tried

`s= s.replaceFirst("(?i)S", "t"); [which of course didn't work]`

and have experimented trying to split the string using a 
string [] `.split(Pattern.quote("\\s"))` then trying to figure out how to `replaceFirst()` each element of the `array` and then **return** the values back to a `string` [**but couldn't figure out the right way of doing it**].

I thought `\\G` might help to **restart** at the next word but have gotten no where. Any help using these 3 methods is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you replace 'Is' to 'It' if you only need to replace the 1st 's' or 'S' in each work ? Can you correct the layout and give one or more clear example ?

Comment: Got it the first occurence of each 's' or 'S'

Comment: @Hedgebox I hope you have got your answer. But have provided a different approach to solve your problem. See my answer.

Comment: One liner in JavaScript: `.replace(/(\S*?)([sS])(\S*)/g, (_, $1, $2, $3) => $1 + ($2 == 's' ? 't' : 'T') + $3)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach-1:** Without using `replace` and `split` method for better performance.

```
String str = "Is Mississippi a State where there are many systems.";
System.out.println(str);

char[] cArray = str.toCharArray();
boolean isFirstS = true;
for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
    if ((cArray[i] == 's' || cArray[i] == 'S') && isFirstS) {
        cArray[i] = (cArray[i] == 's' ? 't' : 'T');
        isFirstS = false;
    } else if (Character.isWhitespace(cArray[i])) {
        isFirstS = true;
    }
}
str = new String(cArray);

System.out.println(str);
```

**EDIT: Approach2:** As you need to use `replaceFirst` method and you dont want to use `StringBuilder` here is an option for you:

```
String input = "Is Mississippi a State where there are many Systems.";
String[] parts = input.split(" ");
String output = "";

 for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
     int smallSIndx = parts[i].indexOf("s");
     int capSIndx = parts[i].indexOf("S");

     if (smallSIndx != -1 && (capSIndx == -1 || smallSIndx < capSIndx))
         output += parts[i].replaceFirst("s", "t") + " ";
     else
         output += parts[i].replaceFirst("S", "T") + " ";
 }

System.out.println(output); //It Mitsissippi a Ttate where there are many Tystems.
```

***Note:*** I prefer **approach 1** because it has *no overhead* for the method  `replaceFisrt` and `split` , String `append` or `concat`

Comment: @cricket_007 edited by going to different approach :)

Comment: ASCII shifting... It'll work, but it is very specific to this one problem

Comment: @cricket_007 yes.... but I hope this will provide a faster solution than other answer.

Comment: @mmuzahid: tks for your solution but I am trying to get a better understanding of the uses of replaceFirst...without the use of StringBuilder at this point.

Comment: @Hedgebox , I've used no ``StringBuilder`` at my solution just used Character Array.

Comment: @mmuzahid: but I want to use replaceFirst in my solution...like Tim Biegeleisen  and Thush-Fdo have provided...

Comment: @Hedgebox I got your point... then go with their answer. I've provided an alternative for better performance. ``split`` ``replace`` replaceFirsrt`` ``append`` methods has their own overhead. I just avoid those for performance issue by using single ``for`` loop to iterate character array.

Comment: @Hedgebox , Plz see EDIT part , May be it serve your purpose using ``replaceFirst``

Answer (score 10):

One option would be to split the string into words, and then use `String.replaceFirst()` on each word to replace the first occurrence of `s` with `t` (or any other letter you want):

**Update:**

I refactored my solution to find the first occurrence of any `s` (upper or lower case), and to apply the appropriate conversion on it.

```
String input = "Is Mississippi a State where there are many systems.";
String[] parts = input.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

for (int i=0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    if (i > 0) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    int index = parts[i].toLowerCase().indexOf('s');
    if (index >= 0 && parts[i].charAt(index) == 's') {
        sb.append(parts[i].replaceFirst("s", "t"));
    }
    else {
        sb.append(parts[i].replaceFirst("S", "T"));
    }
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
It Mitsissippi a Ttate where there are many tystems.
```

Comment: @im-biegeleisen your solution is perfect with some adjustments. Check my post

Comment: This gets the wrong result for a word like "Systems" with a capital "S" and lower case "s" (at least as I understood the question).

Comment: `Systems` -> `Tyttems` ... what is the problem?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : msandiford seems to be correct... I just tried it...I would want "Systems" to become "Tystems"... only the 1st occurance of either "S" or "s" to "T" or "t"

Comment: @Hedgebox I updated my answer per your requirements.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : 2 things...I am trying to avoid the use of StringBuilder for now...also shouldn't... sb.append(parts[i].replaceFirst("s", "t"); be.... sb.append(parts[i].replaceFirst("s", "t")); closing ")" ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `StringBuilder`.  In any case, feel free to replace it with `String` concatenation.

Comment: @BDCoder Sorry, I had a couple of typos in there.  I have fixed them and I verified that the actual output matches what is expected.

Answer (score 3):

Use below amendment to Tim Biegeleisen's answer (before editing his post)

```
String input = "Is Mississippi a State where there are many systems.";
String[] parts = input.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

for (String part : parts) {
    sb.append(part.replaceFirst("s", "t").replaceFirst("S", "T"));
    sb.append(" ");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Edit - You can use concat()**

```
String input = "Is Mississippi a State where there are many systems.";
String[] parts = input.split(" ");

String output = "";

for (String part : parts) {
    output = output.concat(part.replaceFirst("s", "t").replaceFirst("S", "T") + " ");
}

    System.out.println(output);
```

**Update**

```
    String input = "Is Mississippi a State where there are many Systems.";
    String[] parts = input.split(" ");
    //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

    String output = "";

    for (String part : parts) {
        output = output.concat(part.replaceFirst("s", "t") + " ");
    }

    String[] parts2 = output.split(" ");

    output = "";

    for (String part : parts2) {
        output = output.concat(part.replaceFirst("S", "T") + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: I do want to use String methods...is there a way to do it without using StringBuilder?

Comment: @Hedgebox  *FYI* ``StringBuilder`` provides better performance than ``+``

Comment: @Thush-Fdo: msandiford in his comment below...seems to be correct... I just tried it...I would want "Systems" to become "Tystems"... only the 1st occurance of either "S" or "s" to "T" or "t". When I changes "systems" to "Systems" the code produced "Tyttems" not "Tystems".

Comment: @Hedgebox : Another solution to come up with this by using two loops as I've update my answer. But this cost your performance. Feel free to use any of the suggestions.

Comment: @Thush-Fdo dont take it other-wise, too many EDIT in your answer confused some people to understand.

Comment: @Thush-Fdo:  I may have something wrong...but when I try your update my output is ...Is Mississippi a Ttate where there are many Tystems.  Should String[] parts2 = input.split(" "); actually be String[] parts2 = output.split(" ");

Comment: `String.concat` is conventionally written as `+` - it is both easier to read and quicker to write.

Comment: @Thush-Fdo : an update to my running your code....even if I change the code to "output.split" I still am having issues....my output becomes... "It Mitsissippi a Ttate where there are many Tyttems." ...when I leave it as "input.split" my output is "Is Mississippi a Ttate where there are many Tystems." instead of "It Mitsissippi a Ttate where there are many Tystems."

Answer (score 2):

I've created a method that -

- is general purpose,
- doesn't use `replace` or `split`, and
- only uses one loop.

The following is my code snippet:

```
public static String replaceFirstOccurance(String sentence, char toChange, char changeWith) {
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

    boolean changed = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        if (!changed) {
            if (sentence.charAt(i) == toChange) {
                temp.append(changeWith);
                changed = true;
            } else if (sentence.charAt(i) == Character.toUpperCase(toChange)) {
                temp.append(Character.toUpperCase(changeWith));
                changed = true;
            } else {
                temp.append(sentence.charAt(i));
            }
        } else {
            if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                changed = false;
            }
            temp.append(sentence.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    return temp.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My method would be less dependent on those string methods you've mentioned.

```
String phrase;
String [] parts = phrase.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < parts[i].length(); j++) {
        if (parts[i].charAt(j) == 's') {
            parts[i] = "t" + parts[i].substring(1);
            break;
        } else if (parts[i].charAt(0) == 'S') {
            parts[i] = "T" + parts[i].substring(1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

String modifiedPhrase = "";

for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ ) {
    modifiedPhrase += parts[i] + " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a nice, compact, stream-based solution for that:

```
String result = Stream.of(s.split(" "))
    .map(t -> t.replaceFirst("s", "t"))
    .map(t -> t.replaceFirst("S", "T"))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String ss = "Is Mississippi a State where there are many systems.";

String out = "";//replaced string
for (String s : ss.split(" ")) {
    int index = s.toUpperCase().indexOf('S');
    out += (s.replaceFirst("[s,S]", index!= -1 && s.charAt(index) == 'S' 
               ? "T" : "t")) + " ";
}

System.out.println(out);
```